# img tag not working with relative path in src

Tags: html, css, image

This is not working:

```
<img src="../assets/images/image.jpg" alt="Alternative Text">
```

But this is working:

```
<img src="http://localhost/abc/def/geh/assets/images/image.jpg" alt="Alternative Text">
```

In my scenario, I just cannot work with absolute path. I have to use relative path.

Comment: What's the URL of the page this HTML is on?

Comment: localhost/asdf/asdf/asdf/asdf/index.php

Comment: Inspect the `img` element, right-click on the `src` and  __Open image in new tab__ to see the url that it's trying to get. You can also see it in the console and the network tab.

Comment: @miro yes I have done that. It is showing the image in either way when I run in netbeans. But when I run on browser, it doesn't work

Comment: Make a `test.html` with only the 2 `img` tags inside (the relative and abs) and see if that works... Also, did you check other browsers?

Comment: @miro The absolute is working fine. Relative is not working!

Answer (score 17):

```
<img src="assets/images/image.jpg" alt="Alternative Text">
```

should be working.You shouldn't have put '../' at the begining of the image path.

For better understanding about relative paths vs. absolute paths, refer [this link](https://www.jquery-az.com/html-img-src-image-source-attribute-with-path-possibilities-5-examples/)

Answer (score 13):

"../assets/images/image.jpg" -This means

1. '../' go up one directory from where I am now
2. find the 'assets/' folder
3. find the 'images' folder
4. find the 'image.jpg' file.

That relative link will only work if your page is in a subfolder in

"http://localhost/abc/def/geh/"

If the location of your page really is

"localhost/asdf/asdf/asdf/asdf/index.php"

(which seems ridiculous) to get to the assets folder relatively you would have to go all the way to the root.

'../../../../abc/deh/geh/assets/images/image.jpg;

Alternatively you could use a base tag in your head tag to make the URL in the actual src attribute more friendly.

Comment: Unless of course the `assets` folder really is one directory above the current document. However, you're the first person to think of even asking in the first place, so for that, kudos.

Answer (score 3):

**src path for Express apps**

If you are using **Node.js** with **Express** framework, the other answers will not solve your problem.

As said in [Express' official documentation](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html):

> To serve static files such as images, CSS files, and JavaScript files,
> use the express.static built-in middleware function in Express.

So you have to declare the folder of your static files. If, for instance, your image is located in:

```
[project root]/assets/images/image.jpg
```

then you should include in your main javascript file (e.g. index.js or app.js):

```
app.use(express.static('assets'))
```

then your img tag would look like:

```
<img src="/images/image.jpg" alt="Alternative Text">
```

Again, the documentation says:

> Express looks up the files relative to the static directory, so the
> name of the static directory is not part of the URL.

Therefore, in this example you should omit "assets" in the src path, and also note the opening "/".

Answer (score 2):

I suspect you didn't actually do what I told you to so here is a screenshot:

[image]

If the image opens in a new tab then you have some kind of bug or extension that's messing it up in the html. If you messed up the relative path, you'll most likely get 404 but you'll be able to see the path as absolute.
It may look like `http://localhost/asdf/asdf/asdf/asdf/assets/assets/image.jpg`
 Either way, send a screenshot of the above operation.

Answer (score 1):

I will make your life very very simple.
Use it in following manner

```html
<img src="../image_store/Part2.jpg" alt="Dress Picture"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

One thing you can ckeck: is your current page url ends with "/". So when I have url like http://127.0.0.1:7777/www/ then all my relative urls working but then I use it as http://127.0.0.1:7777/www  (no "/" at the end) browsers thinks "www" is file and not a folder. May be this can be configured somehow serverside (in my case I run custom http server software written by me).

Answer (score 0):

import the content into a variable on top of the JSX with the `"src/assets/images/..."` path and use it in the button src (See below example code). start with `src/...` before `assets/...`

```
import imageContent from 'src/assets/images/image.jpg';

.
.
.

<img src={imageContent}/>
```

Answer (score -1):

Do not right click and copy relative path.
Simply follow the syntax below
**<img src="ImageFolderName\filename"**

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -4):

In React:

1. import the image:

   ```
   import image from '../../assets/random-image.png'
   ```
2. use the imported variable as a value of a `src` attribute:

   ```
   <img src={image} />
   ```

Comment: This is not a [tag:react] question

Comment: Thanks this helped me get my logo on the Navbarbrand in React

Comment: This helped me too in React. Thanks a lot!

Comment: thanks @Eduard, this helped solve my problem!