# Image tag in html won't work

Tags: html, image

Even though my html file and image are in the same file the img tag won't find my image. All that is displayed is a tiny image logo, I have also tried all the ../../ etc. but it won't find. The image name is correct too..[index.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mm6wf.png)

Comment: How are we supposed to help you with the information (or rather lack thereof) provided?

Comment: Do not make a screen shot of the code

Comment: Also, check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24028561/relative-path-in-html or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31397137/img-tag-not-working-with-relative-path-in-src or any of the other questions dealing with the exact same issue.

Comment: Can you please add a screenshot of the directory in which your html file and images are stored?

Comment: If you image situated in corren directiory where you Page.html you make all correct but may be you got image with another format like jpg,png, or may be some else. So try to see you mistake in write name of you IMG

Comment: [Edit] your screenshoot into a block code a picture add nothing here. For fixing your path you can use a real EDI or Add to your question the path to your Html and the path to your file.

Answer (score 0):

From you screenshot, it looks like the image tag is working fine and the image is there, but you have the wrong file location.

Is the image you're trying to display inside a directory different to the `index.html` file? if so you need to do `directory/image.jpg` etc

Comment: Thanks for making me aware that OP actually gave us a picture. I'm curious though how you know that the image file is actually there? I can't spot that on the picture.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, the default error image thumbnail is appearing below the li element.

Comment: Ah, you're referring to the `img` element, not the actual image file in the file system I take it.

Comment: Yes, the tag seems to be working correctly as far as I can see. I thinks it's an issue with location etc, hopefully OP can show me the directory.

Answer (score -2):

Start renaming your file all in lowercase.

Comment: While I would personally agree with this *style recommendation*, there is no technical need for this. Also, it does not directly address the OP's question.