# Why don't my href image files appear when i try to test my HTML code

Tags: html

The href tags that I have put in my code lead to images saved on my computer but when I test my code they appear as little broken images.

Moodle, c'est cool.

```
<img src="d6j542d-6fbbd2d6-8801-4016-94aa-63dae5560124.png" alt="wat" width="40px" height="20px">
```

I would like the image to appear, doesn't matter what format, I would just like to see it.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31397137/img-tag-not-working-with-relative-path-in-src/31397530. This question contains the answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is only an image name. In that case the browser will try to find the file in the same folder as the html file. Apparently it is not there. It would make sense to check that first. If it's in a different folder you would have to either move it in the same folder as your html or add the folder(s) where the image is located before the file name (e.g. `src="folder-a/folder-b/image-name.png"`)

A folder called "images" in your project folder would make sense. Then the new link would be:

```
<img src="images/d6j542d-6fbbd2d6-8801-4016-94aa-63dae5560124.png" alt="wat" width="40px" height="20px">
```

(you might also want to consider a more descriptive file name for the image... e.g. logo.png)

Comment: Thanks ! Much appreciated